# How to compare an array in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rspec

Hi I am working on RoR project with ruby-2.5.0 and Rails 5. I have a method on controller which returns an array and the array contains a string and an object of a Reciept Model as follows:

```
["IGA", #<Reciept id: 1, name: "IGA", reciept_date: "2006-02-18 16:25:00", user_id: 1, created_at: "2018-04-07 11:53:33", updated_at: "2018-04-07 11:53:33">]
```

In my rspec i want to compare this array as follows:-

```
it { expect(described_class.find_store(params,user_id)).to eq(["IGA", #<Reciept id: 1, name: "IGA", reciept_date: "2006-02-18 16:25:00", user_id: 1, created_at: "2018-04-07 11:53:33", updated_at: "2018-04-07 11:53:33">]) }
```

It given syntax error as inside the array there is a '#' symbol so it comments my code. Please help me how can i compare this array. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to the following:

```
it { expect(described_class.find_store(params,user_id)).to eq(["IGA", Reciept.find(1)]) }
```

Answer (score 1):

For comparing arrays regardless of ordering, try `match_array`.

```rb
it { expect(described_class.find_store(params,user_id)).to match_array(["IGA", Reciept.find(1)]) }
```

This will pass whether `"IGA"` or `Receipt` comes first.